# Can't more than two strings compare?

Tags: c

If we compared integers we would assign one of them as the largest/smallest one.
However, when I try comparing more than two strings, I can't manage assaigment. 
In my code "for loop" compares two of the strings. This is good method but I need to compare one of them to the others individually. (I can predict that I need to use two for loop, but also I can't implement) What is your suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct wordSorting
{
    char name[15];
    int i = 0;
};

int main()
{
    wordSorting *wordElement = (wordSorting *)malloc(sizeof(wordSorting));
    wordElement = (wordSorting *)malloc(sizeof(wordSorting));

    printf("-- Enter three person name --\n\n");
    for (wordElement->i = 0; wordElement->i < 3; wordElement->i++)
    {
        printf("Enter %d. person name: ", wordElement->i + 1);
        scanf("%s", wordElement[wordElement->i].name);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (wordElement->i = 0; wordElement->i < 3; wordElement->i++)
    {
        if ((strcmp(wordElement[wordElement->i].name, wordElement[wordElement->i + 1].name))<0)
        {
            printf("%s", wordElement[wordElement->i].name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program leaks memory in the first two lines of `main()`, and breaches the allocated memory that sticks around as soon as your loop enter's its second iteration.

Comment: Your mallocs are completely bogus! Why do you use this struct?

Comment: start with make an array of wordSorting. Dont puut the loop counter in wordSorting. You dont have to malloc this array. And then look at the line of the compare. and think what is the problem in this line..

Comment: Honestly, drop the structure entirely. It is literally no help to this problem *at all*. The `typedef struct ...` doesn't even name a type alias. This can't even *compile*.

Answer (score 0):

**First**

```
typedef struct wordSorting
{
    char name[15];
    int i = 0;
};
```

Members of typedef/struct cannot be initied.
That is not the way to define a typedef, change it as:

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[15];
    int i;
}wordSorting;
```

**Second:**

```
wordElement = (wordSorting *)malloc(sizeof(wordSorting));
```

makes no sense. malloc returns void pointer, and you already init your variable at the first element in the first line of code.
And, as someone edited: do not cast malloc return, please.

**Third, :**

```
wordSorting *wordElement = (wordSorting *)malloc(sizeof(wordSorting));
wordElement = (wordSorting *)malloc(sizeof(wordSorting));

printf("-- Enter three person name --\n\n");
for (wordElement->i = 0; wordElement->i < 3; wordElement->i++)
{
    printf("Enter %d. person name: ", wordElement->i + 1);
    scanf("%s", wordElement[wordElement->i].name);
}
```

You are allocating space for one element, no array are defined then `wordElement[wordElement->i].name` is undefined Behaviour.

**Finally**

I don't know what compiler are you using, but gcc cannot compile such a bad code full of errors...

**Suggestion.**

What I think you need is to use array, but you must allocate the number of member you need, by:

```
wordSorting *wordElement = malloc(sizeof(wordSorting)*num_of_elements);
```

or simply, using a local array:

```
wordSorting wordElement[num_of_elements];
```

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry, I commited a draft of the answer. I edited.

Comment: `typedef` is redundant in your definition